# Angular Reactive Form with Validation: ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstName' of undefined

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I tried **Reactive Form** with some validations, I am trying to showing an error when First name field is empty. But It showing "**ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstName' of undefined**"

This is my .ts file's code

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import{FormGroup, FormControl, FormBuilder, NgForm, Validators} from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-reactiveform',
  templateUrl: './reactiveform.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./reactiveform.component.css']
})
export class ReactiveformComponent implements OnInit {

  signupForm:FormGroup;
  fName:string="";
  lName:string="";
  emailID:string="";
  pswd:string="";

  constructor(private formBuilder:FormBuilder) {
    this.signupForm=formBuilder.group({
      firstName: ['', Validators.required],
      lastName: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(10)]],
      Emailid: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
      PasswordN: ['', Validators.required]
    });
   }


  PostData(signupForm:any){
    console.log(signupForm.controls);
  }


  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
```

It is my conponet.html page's code. Error showing in this line:  Enter Your First Name

```
                <form [formGroup]='signupForm' (ngSubmit)="PostData(signupForm)">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name" formControlName="firstName" />
                        <div *ngFor="signupForm.control['firstName'].haserror(required)"> Enter Your First Name </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Last Name" formControlName="lastName" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" formControlName="Emailid" />
                    </div>   
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" formControlName="PasswordN" />
                    </div>                 
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn bg-success text-white" [disabled]='!signupForm.valid' > Register </button>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

Comment: I could be in your HTML : ```signupForm.controls['firstName']``` with a ```s``` at the end of ```controls```

Answer (score 0):

As commented by @Olivier, it must be:

```
signupForm.controls['firstName']...
```

and `haserror()` returns a boolean value in which case *ngFor will not be applicable instead use *ngIf.

So your HTML code will be:

```
<div *ngIf="signupForm.controls['firstName'].haserror(required)"> Enter Your First Name </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the line

```js
<div *ngFor="signupForm.control['firstName'].haserror(required)"> Enter Your First Name </div>
```

To this line

```js
 <div *ngIf="signupForm.controls.firstName.hasError('required')"> Enter Your First Name </div>
```